# How to transpose some rows to columns?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

There were a lot of questions with transpose but I have some specifics and can't create the right formula.
So I have near 100k rows in the following format

[image: 0]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/146-6YHv69DDOnPKheKeRFZIQeZYIgO6UwCMd7X9VeKU/edit?usp=sharing 
I need `ARRAYFORMULA` or something like that to make this 100k rows in the format that you can see on the "Expected Outcome" tab.

[image: 0]

Comment: Welcome. FYI, StackOverflow isn't a bespoke coding service. It would be very helpful if you were to describe your own efforts at resolving this problem.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.
But it may be very helpful for someone with the same issue.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Stack is always the place where I go for critical situations and always meet good and crazy people! have a good evening. Will see you later.

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(INDIRECT("source!A2:A"&COUNTA(source!A2:A))),
 QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY("♦"&INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(source!B2:J<>"", "♦"&source!A2:A&"♠"&{"♥"&source!B2:B, source!C2:J}, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99)), "♦")), "♠"),,2),,999^99), "♥")), "♦"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Tour de force. Might I ask how long it took you to construct?

Comment: @Tedinoz took me about 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You have a vast number of records but there are 19 data fields to each record spread over 10 columns & 12 rows. You suggested an arrayformula (and much more clever people than I can probably do that), but I suggest a script which takes the data in its current form on one sheet (say the 'source'), and which outputs the data to a new sheet (say, the 'target').

There are a couple of issues to be addressed in "mapping" the data:

- how many records are represented on the input sheet - required to enable looping. I used the Javascript `Math.floor` method to calculate the number of products.
- identify the correct row/column combination for each field. The data is in three segments

  - 8 fields in contiguous columns in the first row,
  - 2 fields in 2 rows in the ninth column, and
  - 9 fields in nine contiguous rows in the tenth column.
  - Total = 12 rows/10 columns. To do this, in order to navigate the rows, I took the counter (i) multiplied by the number of rows, plus 1; the columns are more intuitive.
- for efficiency,

  - get data once only at the beginning of the script;
  - use arrays to progressively build the output; and
  - update the output (`setValues`) once at the end of the script.

---

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourcesheetname = "source";
  var targetsheetname = "target";
  var source = ss.getSheetByName(sourcesheetname);
  var target = ss.getSheetByName(targetsheetname);

  var sourcerange = source.getDataRange();
  var sourcedata = sourcerange.getValues();

  var sourceheaders = 1;
  var rowsperproduct = 12;

  var sourcelr = source.getLastRow();

  var integerPart = Math.floor((sourcelr-sourceheaders)/rowsperproduct);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: number of products = "+integerPart);

  var rowdata = [];

  // look thought the number of products
  for (var i = 0; i<integerPart; i++){

    // use a temporary array to build the data for the row.
    var temp = [];
    // row 1, copy first eight columns (0-7)
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+1][0]);//ID
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+1][1]);//GID
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+1][2]);//NAME
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+1][3]);//PRICE
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+1][4]);//BRAND
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+1][5]);//URL
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+1][6]);//country
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+1][7]);//instock

    // row 2 & 3 in Column I(8)
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+2][8]);//url1
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+3][8]);//url2

    // rows 4 - 12 in Column J(9)
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+4][9]);// tech name
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+5][9]);// size
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+6][9]);// inches
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+7][9]);// mm
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+8][9]);// depth
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+9][9]);// BB
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+10][9]);// ref1
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+11][9]);// ref2
    temp.push(sourcedata[(i*12)+12][9]);// ref3

    // Update the rowdata for this row
    rowdata.push(temp);

  }

  // update data to target
  target.getRange(2,1,integerPart,19).setValues(rowdata);
}
```